# Embedding external URLs behind text in Tomboy

Tags: tomboy

Is there any way to embed a URL to an external web page in the text of a tomboy note, in the same way that other notes are linked to? I know I can just pates the URL into the note and have it link out, but when the link is over a hundred characters long (not kidding) and I have a lot of them then that stops being an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this isn't currently possible in Tomboy, unless you develop a custom add-in to do it.

We might add this feature in a future version, though.